# how to count all my divs using f12

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser

I have a page with different tags and I need to count all the div tags on page but I can't use the code. Is there a way in F12 option to count all the tags from a specific type?(chrome or IE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the console, do:

`document.getElementsByTagName("div").length`